# Data Listing Request

Tags: data-request

I’m about to start on my project for a university degree.

To embark on it, I am looking for data listing, of any kind & preferably clean data. 
The requirement is to obtain a data listing (size of at least in ten thousands), run it through IBM software and present the data to school (with the hope of getting a really good grade for it). 
Can someone pls advise me where I can get data listing to be used for the project? Thanks!

Comment: you just need a catalog of some large amount of data?  I can give you a dump of millions of records describing solar images.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys! Hi Joe, when you say "records describing solar images" are the data textual data? I don't want textual data coz i am pretty bad at text mining. >_< Hi Anastasios, nope I am not looking for list with sources for open data.
I am looking for a dataset that has a large amount of data in it. An example, is customers who defaulted on their loans has data listing with columns like amount defaulted, loan outstanding, demographics profile, etc.....

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're just looking for any large structured dataset to play with. If you could be more specific of the type of data you're interested in, we could probably provide some more targeted recommendations.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/campeterson/5946446) provides a good list of sample open data sets, including some curated collections by data scientists.

I particularly like [Hilary Mason's research-quality dataset list](https://bitly.com/bundles/hmason/1).

My advice is to pick a dataset related to a subject you're interested in. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have undestood you well. But are you looking for something like this one?

A list with sources for open data: [Open data catalogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_data#Major_sources_of_open_data)